# How to set 45th bit in a 64 bit register field?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I was trying to set 46th bit in a register which of 64 bits wide using C.How do i go about setting this bit ?

Currently i am doing this:

```
uint32_t= address ;
uint64_t data =1ULL << 46;
```

Printing this is showing that bit 14 is getting set.I am not able to set even bit 32. If i set bit 32 it sets bit 0. 33 will set bit 1. Looks like it is doing circular shifting after 0-31 again it starts over with 0.

Register in 64 bit wide.

Any idea how do i go about setting this bit ?

Eg:

```
reg_addr.val = FEATURE_REG;

printf(stdout, "Programming enable at address %x=%llx\n",
    reg_addr.val,reg_addr.val);

data.val = (1ULL << 46);

printf("Data value %llx\n",data.val);}
```

Comment: @Thej No you aren't, you have asked 8 questions, and there are 5 of them where you should consider what was the best answer you received.

Comment: Your compiler seems buggy. Try `(1ULL << 23) << 23` and see whether that works around the problem.

Comment: Can you show a complete example? Because the shift is correct.

Comment: How are you checking what the bit is set?

Comment: I am reading the register value back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use types as uint32_t or uint64_t printing correctly is done with:

```
printf(stdout, "Programming enable at address %" PRIu32 "=%" PRIu64 "\n",reg_addr.addr, reg_addr.val);
```

assuming reg_addr.addr is of type uint32_t and type reg_addr.val is of uint64_t.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct.

You should check that 64-bit integer types are correctly supported in your platform:

```
printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof 1ULL, sizeof data);
```

should print

```
8 8
```

If this is the case, the error is probably (as mentioned by @pmg in the comments) in how you check if the bit is set.

In the new edit, you mentioned it is a register. IO registers can have special behavior due to their volatile property. I suggest you to first check to set a bit with a normal object.

Comment: I have a function which reads the data from the device and it gets saved in this format                                          (unsigned char*)&data.                                                      This data value is what i am reading and printing and this data is declared as uint64_t

Answer (score 0):

I hope you do not check the output of this line to conclude the shifting is not done correctly!?

> printf(stdout, "Programming enable at address %x=%llx\n", reg_addr.val,reg_addr.val);

Passing the 64 bit value two times to `printf`, but using %x (probably 32 bit) and %llx (64 bit) to output the values will not work. I guess you meant to take the address of reg_addr.val at the first parameter!?

> printf(stdout, "Programming enable at address %x=%llx\n", &reg_addr.val,reg_addr.val);