# How to set *any* bit in a Java long, even if bit position > 30

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, long-integer

I'm familiar with how to set and clear specific bits in a Java numeric variable.  But I'm not sure how to manipulate any bits in position > 30 in a `long`.

I've read that Java handles `longs` as two `ints` for heap sizes less than 30gb.  Setting my heap size to 45gb (on an EC2 instance) didn't help.

I confirmed that I'm using 64 bit Java:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_71"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_71-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.71-b15, mixed mode)
```

**Is there any way to change bits in any position in a Java `long`?**

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207611/how-to-set-45th-bit-in-a-64-bit-register-field) is the same question, but for C.  But it wasn't helpful for me.

Here is the code and output that illustrates my predicament.  As you can see, it works great up through the 31st bit.

```
private static long setBit(long bits, int bitPosition) {
  return bits | (1 << bitPosition);
}

private static long clearBit(long bits, int bitPosition) {
  return bits & ~(1 << bitPosition);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

  for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {

    long myLong = clearBit(Long.MAX_VALUE, i);

    System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(myLong) + " " + i + " " + myLong);
  }
}
```

output:

```
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110 0 9223372036854775806
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101 1 9223372036854775805
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111011 2 9223372036854775803
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110111 3 9223372036854775799
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101111 4 9223372036854775791
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111011111 5 9223372036854775775
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110111111 6 9223372036854775743
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101111111 7 9223372036854775679
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111011111111 8 9223372036854775551
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110111111111 9 9223372036854775295
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101111111111 10 9223372036854774783
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111011111111111 11 9223372036854773759
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110111111111111 12 9223372036854771711
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101111111111111 13 9223372036854767615
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111011111111111111 14 9223372036854759423
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110111111111111111 15 9223372036854743039
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101111111111111111 16 9223372036854710271
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111011111111111111111 17 9223372036854644735
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110111111111111111111 18 9223372036854513663
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101111111111111111111 19 9223372036854251519
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111011111111111111111111 20 9223372036853727231
111111111111111111111111111111111111111110111111111111111111111 21 9223372036852678655
111111111111111111111111111111111111111101111111111111111111111 22 9223372036850581503
111111111111111111111111111111111111111011111111111111111111111 23 9223372036846387199
111111111111111111111111111111111111110111111111111111111111111 24 9223372036837998591
111111111111111111111111111111111111101111111111111111111111111 25 9223372036821221375
111111111111111111111111111111111111011111111111111111111111111 26 9223372036787666943
111111111111111111111111111111111110111111111111111111111111111 27 9223372036720558079
111111111111111111111111111111111101111111111111111111111111111 28 9223372036586340351
111111111111111111111111111111111011111111111111111111111111111 29 9223372036317904895
111111111111111111111111111111110111111111111111111111111111111 30 9223372035781033983
1111111111111111111111111111111 31 2147483647
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110 32 9223372036854775806
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101 33 9223372036854775805
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111011 34 9223372036854775803
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110111 35 9223372036854775799
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101111 36 9223372036854775791
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111011111 37 9223372036854775775
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110111111 38 9223372036854775743
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101111111 39 9223372036854775679
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111011111111 40 9223372036854775551
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110111111111 41 9223372036854775295
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101111111111 42 9223372036854774783
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111011111111111 43 9223372036854773759
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110111111111111 44 9223372036854771711
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101111111111111 45 9223372036854767615
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111011111111111111 46 9223372036854759423
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110111111111111111 47 9223372036854743039
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101111111111111111 48 9223372036854710271
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111011111111111111111 49 9223372036854644735
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110111111111111111111 50 9223372036854513663
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101111111111111111111 51 9223372036854251519
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111011111111111111111111 52 9223372036853727231
111111111111111111111111111111111111111110111111111111111111111 53 9223372036852678655
111111111111111111111111111111111111111101111111111111111111111 54 9223372036850581503
111111111111111111111111111111111111111011111111111111111111111 55 9223372036846387199
111111111111111111111111111111111111110111111111111111111111111 56 9223372036837998591
111111111111111111111111111111111111101111111111111111111111111 57 9223372036821221375
111111111111111111111111111111111111011111111111111111111111111 58 9223372036787666943
111111111111111111111111111111111110111111111111111111111111111 59 9223372036720558079
111111111111111111111111111111111101111111111111111111111111111 60 9223372036586340351
111111111111111111111111111111111011111111111111111111111111111 61 9223372036317904895
111111111111111111111111111111110111111111111111111111111111111 62 9223372035781033983
1111111111111111111111111111111 63 2147483647
```

Thank you for reading - any guidance/code/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1<<32` will overflow since it is `int`.
You have to change it to `long`.

```
return bits | (1L << bitPosition)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private static long clearBit(long bits, int bitPosition) {
  return bits & ~(1l << bitPosition);
}
```

1 without a l is a int, that is your bug.